# Correct EAX value and what is eiz?

Tags: assembly, x86, gdb, reverse-engineering, ida

I am doing the **CMU bomb challenge** and am stuck at  **( phase 6 )** .

While debugging using GDB I couldn't understand two things , please look into the screenshots for clarity.

### Doubt 1 :

As you can see the current instruction to be executed is

```
mov    eax,DWORD PTR [edx+ecx*1]
```

and the value in registers :

**EDX : 0xc**
**ECX : 0x1**

#### Before Execution : 1st Screenshot

[image: Before Execution]

So after calculation the value moved should be **0xd** , however it is **0x4** , as you can see in the 2nd screenshot below.

#### After Execution : 2nd Screenshot

[image: After Execution]

#### Doubt 2 :

In the above screenshot ( where it's marked as **2** ) , what is **eiz**, as gdb is showing ?

#### IDA disassembly of the same 2 instructions

[image: IDA Disassembly]

### Update :

*After some comments although **Doubt 2** was cleared but raised some basic doubts about register addressing*

#### Doubt 3:

Assume  : 
**edx = 0xffffd120 and [edx] = 2**
**ecx = 0xffffd130 and [ecx] = 3**
**[0x4ffff15e0] = 7**

```
mov    eax,DWORD PTR [edx+ecx*4]
```

Is the above expression equivalent to this : **eax = [edx] +[ecx]*4** (i.e. 2 + 3*4 = 0xd )  ?

Or to this : **eax = [edx + ecx*4]** ( i.e. 7 )  
i.e. `0xffffd120+0xffffd130*4 = 0x4ffff15e0 ==> [0x4ffff15e0]`

Comment: EIZ is a pseudo register. It simply evaluates to zero. The `lea esi,[esi*eiz*1+0x0]` in fact is just along _NOP_ that doesn't do anything  except load ESI into itself. This type of NOP exists to align the top of a loop to a 16-byte boundary for performance reasons. You'll notice that the next instruction is on an address `0x8048e30` evenly divisible by 16 (lower 4 bits of address are 0)

Comment: `mov    eax,DWORD PTR [edx+ecx*1] ` takes what is at memory address pointed to by `edx+ecx*1` and places the 32-bit value into _EAX_

Comment: The `ecx` in first step is `0xffffd130`, not `0x01`. That `1` looks as value which is stored in memory at that address, but I would prefer to see memory view to be sure, which bytes are stored in memory. By a guess I would say it shows `dword` value. If it would be 1, the `mov eax,[edx+ecx*1]` would try to fetch value from address `0x0d`, which would any modern OS in user-mode cause segfault due to invalid memory access (the low addresses around zero are off limits for reading).

Comment: 2 totally separate questions, but now that SO supports multiple duplicate targets, we can take care of them both.  (You apparently were thinking that `mov eax, [edx + ecx]` did `eax=edx+ecx` instead of a load.)

Comment: Thanks @PeterCordes. Looked into those two links , seems to answer my question but not totally ( second doubt was answered perfectly )

Comment: @MichaelPetch do you mean value at **0xffff1d30 + 0xc i.e. [0xffff1d3c]** ?

Comment: Yes, exactly `[0xffff1d30 + 0xc]` (EDX+ECX) is the memory address that the value was read from, and according to the output that value happened to be 4 (as that was loaded into _EAX_)

Comment: @MichaelPetch Thanks a lot

Comment: doubt3: no, that's not how x86 addressing modes work.  It's an address calculation, not multiple loads.  I added another duplicate to the list.